# Web Essentials vs. MVC Bundling

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

Web Essentials for VS20XX offers a bundling feature which I've used. I haven't ever really used the MVC bundling feature. Are there any major differences in functionality? Is it best practice to use the MVC?

In the actual case in question, I'm using OWIN/Katana, MVC 5.

Comment: It might be helpful for others to mention one big advantage of MVC over Web Essentials is that the bundle won't work correctly (obviously) without WebEssentials installed. I just ran into this today.

Comment: It also might be worth mentioning that I've found it difficult to set up bundling using the MVC style in OWIN, so that might be a win for Web Essentials...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few differences. I don't think a "best practice" exists beyond what you want to work for. Obviously Web Essentials isn't going to be as integrated into MVC as the MVC bundler is. A few points on the MVC bundler.

1. The MVC bundler won't bundle Less, Sass, CS etc. without a plugin.
   So if you have less files for example, you need something like
   dotless.
2. It won't bundle images into sprites.
3. It supports file versioning so no action is required when jquery
   goes from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1, though since bundles are generated on
   application start it's a little harder to manage bundle versioning.
4. There is no manual building of bundles besides defining the Bundle
   config file
5. Turning bundling and minification on/off is as easy as turning
   on/off debug mode in the web config or enabling optimizations in the
   bundle config.
6. It supports bundling of CDNs
7. When your server is running you can make edits to individual files and the bundle will regenerate at runtime

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Shoe's answer, I think these are also worth mentioning:

- Less, Sass plugins often require extra work and problems: I have tried dotless, but it couldn't compile Bootstrap Less source, as it's engine was outdated. I have tried other plugin, which required JavaScript engine, which required installing C++ Redistributables on the server.
- WebEssentials compiles, minifies and bundles files on save and build, while MVC bundling does that on AppStart. The effect is longer application start time, what can be a problem when IIS kills application often in a favour of other applications